# How do I get the id of the row I just inserted using a single prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I'm inserting a row in the following way:

```
require("localhost_credentials.php");

$conn = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
if($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$q_title = $fixed_title;
$q_tags = $_POST['tag_input'];
$q_mod = "n";
$q_t_create = date("m/d/Y @ G:i:s");
$q_t_modified = date("m/d/Y @ G:i:s");

$querystr  = "INSERT INTO mytable (title, tags, moderator, time_created, time_last_modified) ";
$querystr .= "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

$statement = $conn->prepare($querystr);
$statement->bind_param("sssss", $q_title, $q_tags, $q_mod, $q_t_create, $q_t_modified);
$statement->execute();
```

I would like to get the id of the row I just inserted without having to do a second query.  I've seen a few methods to do this on SO, but every time there's a debate as to which way it should and should not be done and I'm kind of confused.

Using prepared statements, how do I get the id of a newly inserted row using only one query?

Comment: Use PHP's built-in function http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you do not execute multi insert, you can use

```
$conn->insert_id
```

It is populated automatically when a statement created from that connection executes INSERT query.

Comment: Actually now it's always returning zero?

Comment: Figured it out.  It was failing because I was sending the same data over and over, and the title column in the table is set to unique so I couldn't add a row with the same title.

Comment: Great you figured it out! :-) Keep in mind that Statement object can also give you *insert_id* the same way the connection can.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this :

```
$last_id = $statement->insert_id($conn);
```

this will return the last inserted row id .